# How set the backgroudColor of keyboard when being splited

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

When I am inputting with a split keyboard, the background of the split keyboard is dark black, how to set it the same color with the color of keyboard?

I reset window.frame.y = - 300 when keyboard is shown, and set  window.frame.y = 0 when keyboard is hidden.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that this is e behavior of the keyboard? The split keyboard does not have a background color.

Comment: I do not know. Just want to know how to handle the problem.

Comment: Your view is probably not set to the bottom of the main view. Have you used the Storyboard to create the green view?

Comment: And i  know IQKeyboardmanager can resolve it, but  i do not want to use it.

Comment: It´s not a problem with the keyboard it´s your view, upload your code and share if you have the possibility and I´ll try to help you.

Comment: I set window.frame.y = - 300 when keyboard is shown, and set window.frame.y = 0 when keyboard is hidden.

Comment: Try to set the window.frame.y to -200 or -100 and see whats happens.

Comment: Add your code to the question, hard to help otherwise.